# how to know how many GPUs are used in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed-training

The bash file I used to launch the training looks like this:

```sh
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3,4 python -m torch.distributed.launch \
--nproc_per_node=2  train.py \
--batch_size 6 \
--other_args
```

I found that the batch size of tensors in each GPU is acctually `batch_size / num_of_gpu` = `6/2` = 3.

When I initialize my network, I need to know *the batch size in each GPU*.
(Ps. in this phase, I can't use `input_tensor.shape` to get the size of batch-dimension, since there are no data fed in jet.)

Somehow I could not find where does the pytorch store the parameter `--nproc_per_node`.
So how could I know how many GPUs are used, without passing it manually as `--other_args`?

Comment: Not sure if you can access these args in the child process, but if you always set the cuda visible devices, maybe a workaround could be `len(os.getenv('CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES').split(','))` or `torch.cuda.device_count()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`torch.distributed.get_world_size()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#post-initialization) - this will tell you how many processes were created.